# Any way to print "year" or "years" more efficiently/with less code?

Tags: python

````
max = 30



name= input("what is your name")
print("hello " + name)
age = int(input("how old are you"))

if age >= min and age <= max :
    print("you just earned yourself a free holiday!")
elif age < min:
    if min - age == 1:
        print("sorry " + name + " you are not old enough, please come back in {0} year.".format(min - age) )
    else:
      print("sorry " + name + " you are not old enough, please come back in {0} years.".format(min - age) )
else:
    print("too old ")```
````

the following lines are so if someone has to wait 1 year the program should print "come back in 1 year" not "come back in 1 years":

```
        print("sorry " + name + " you are not old enough, please come back in {0} year.".format(min - age) )
    else:
      print("sorry " + name + " you are not old enough, please come back in {0} years.".format(min - age) )**
```

so i was just wondering if there was a simpler way to do this without adding another if statement.

Comment: Note that Python has built in functions `max` and `min` which find the maximum and minimum of an iterable, respectively. It might be better practice to not overwrite these variable names.

Comment: `"...come back in {0} year(s)".format(min - age)` would probably be sufficient in casual usage. No conditionals necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional expression (`x if y else z`):

```
print("sorry " + name + " you are not old enough, please come back in {0} {1}.".format(min - age, "year" if min - age == 1 else "years") )
```

Or, if your Python is recent enough to support f-strings:

```
print(f"sorry {name} you are not old enough, please come back in {min - age} {"years" if min - age == 1 else "year"}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a f-string for this (or extend the format function you use already)

```
print(f"sorry {name}, you are not old enough, please come back in {min-age} year{'s'*int(min-age>1)}")
```